# Regex to fetch from a command output

Tags: regex

I have below string output

```
Version: 9.1.2(Build:40)
Syntax version:4.00.10
Components:
Engine
Processors
Configuration file: C:/Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/CMConfig.xml

Reports path: C:/Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/CMReports
User logs path: C:/Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/UserLogs

Package identifier: IF_Windows_OS32_x86_C32

License information:
License-file path: C:/Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/CDELicense.cfg
Expiration date: unlimited
Maximum CPUs: 10
Maximum services: unlimited
Licensed components: HL7,BAI,EDI,SWIFT,EDF,HIPAA,ACORD,FIX,TeleKurs,NACHA,SAP Co
nversion Agent,Oracle BPEL,webMethods,BizTalk,IBM Message Broker,Excel,Pdf,Word,
Afp,Ppt
```

I'd like to fetch the value of `Package identifier` i.e., `IF_Windows_OS32_x86_C32` using regex

Comment: What language are you going to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
Package identifier: (\S+)
```

?

Comment: Joey: `Package identifier: (\S+)` selects the whole line, `(?<=Package identifier:) (\S+)` helped me Thanks. Also please tell me what is `\S` here?

Comment: `\S` matches a non-space character.

Comment: Abhishek: That's why there are parentheses around it, so you have that in a group. If you use the lookbehind you should include the space in it as well, so that you can use the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you, but only because you finally got the slashes’ slope correct. :)

```
 /Package identifier: *([^\n]*)/
```

Now the ID is in the first capture group.  Omit the slashes if your regex engine doesn’t need delimiters like that.

Comment: It gives me `Package identifier: IF_Windows_OS32_x86_C32

License information:
License-file path: C:/Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/`

Comment: @Abhisek: Then you misrepresented the input file.